# How to extract currency value from string using regex in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to extract the currency symbol €$ from string using regex.
For Example, if my string contains $40.00, I need to get only the $ symbol from the string, Please guide.
Example String values:
$40.00,
45$,€65,89£.Need to extract any currency.

Comment: Are the symbol always as the first character in the String?

Comment: no, it may be likes 40.00$ also

Comment: Are there only $ and €? Please, give some examples of values and what you expect to extract from it.

Comment: updated please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tactic is to just remove anything from the String which are not part of the number.

```
void main() {
  print(getCurrencySymbol(r'$40.00'));     // $
  print(getCurrencySymbol(r'45$'));        // $
  print(getCurrencySymbol(r'€65,89'));     // €
  print(getCurrencySymbol(r'100,89 DKK')); // DKK
}

String getCurrencySymbol(String value) =>
    value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[-.,0-9 ]'), '');
```

Comment: may i know how to pass value

Comment: final currencyValue = productItem?.totalPrice?.text;
  String symbol = getCurrencySymbol(r'{currencyValue}');

Comment: Please help,may i know how to pass string value

Comment: What type are your `currencyValue` variable? I would guess `String` (since you are calling a property named `text`) so you can just do: `getCurrencySymbol(currencyValue)`? But I guess that is not the case since you are asking?